# How to insert a mini identity matrix (row and column) to the start of Panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe, append

Given a data frame as such:

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+
|  X1 | xyz | opq |  jkl |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| abc | 0.9 | 0.0 |  0.5 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| efg | 0.3 | 0.0 |  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| lmn | 0.0 | 0.23|  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

**How do I add an identity matrix to the start of the dataframe to get this?**:

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
|  X1 | <s> | opq |  jkl |  jkl |
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
| <s> | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0  |  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
| abc | 0.0 | 0.9 | 0.0  |  0.5 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
| efg | 0.0 | 0.3 | 0.0  |  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
| lmn | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.23 |  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
```

That's adding a 1x1 matrix but is there a way to add a nxn matrix, e.g.:

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
|  X1 | <s> | <e> | opq  |  jkl |  jkl |
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
| <s> | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0  |  0.0 |  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
| <e> | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0  |  0.0 |  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
| abc | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.9  | 0.0  |  0.5 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
| efg | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.3  | 0.0  |  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
| lmn | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0  | 0.23 |  0.0 |
+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
```

I've tried this:

```
$ echo -e 'abc\txyz\t0.9\nefg\txyz\t0.3\nlmn\topq\t0.23\nabc\tjkl\t0.5\n' > test.txt
$ cat test.txt
abc xyz 0.9
efg xyz 0.3
lmn opq 0.23
abc jkl 0.5

$ python
>>> from sframe import SFrame
>>> sf = SFrame.read_csv('test.txt', header=False, delimiter='\t', column_type_hints=[unicode, unicode, float])
[INFO] sframe.cython.cy_server: SFrame v2.1 started. Logging /tmp/sframe_server_1479779504.log
>>> df = sf.to_dataframe()
>>> df
    X1   X2    X3
0  abc  xyz  0.90
1  efg  xyz  0.30
2  lmn  opq  0.23
3  abc  jkl  0.50
>>> df = df.pivot(index='X1', columns='X2', values='X3') 
>>> df
X2   jkl   opq  xyz
X1                 
abc  0.5   NaN  0.9
efg  NaN   NaN  0.3
lmn  NaN  0.23  NaN
>>> df.fillna(0) 
X2   jkl   opq  xyz
X1                 
abc  0.5  0.00  0.9
efg  0.0  0.00  0.3
lmn  0.0  0.23  0.0
```

First I added a column:

```
>>> numrow, numcol = df.shape
>>> df.insert(0, '<s>', [0.0] * numrow)
>>> df
X2   <s>  jkl   opq  xyz
X1                      
abc  0.0  0.5  0.00  0.9
efg  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.3
lmn  0.0  0.0  0.23  0.0
```

Then add the row and change the value of `df['<s>']['<s>']`:

```
>>> numrow, numcol = df.shape
>>> df.loc['<s>'] = [0.0]*numcol
>>> df
X2   <s>  jkl   opq  xyz
X1                      
abc  0.0  0.5  0.00  0.9
efg  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.3
lmn  0.0  0.0  0.23  0.0
<s>  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.0
>>> df['<s>']['<s>'] = 1.0
>>> df
X2   <s>  jkl   opq  xyz
X1                      
abc  0.0  0.5  0.00  0.9
efg  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.3
lmn  0.0  0.0  0.23  0.0
<s>  1.0  0.0  0.00  0.0
```

But still I need to swap the last row and put it to the first and push down all other rows in the table. **How do I do that?**

And there must be a better / easier way to do this.

Comment: (I know you're using SFrames initially and they do display with `|` and `+`separators which look good but prevent us from using `pd.read_clipboard()` to import your data. This is just a side node, here you do have regular output later on so that's ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepending to `DataFrame` isn't terribly simple, especially if you're looking to prepend both rows and columns.

Here's the best solution I could come up with, hopefully it isn't too inefficient since you're likely working with large datasets given that you use SFrame.

First, let's define the size of the identity matrix you want to preprend:

```
# Size o
n = 2
```

Now, let's create a new dataframe using `numpy.eye`, prepending new row and column indexes to your existing ones. I could have used `numpy.identity` since your initial dataframe is square, but it wouldn't work if it wasn't.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(n+df.shape[0], n+df.shape[1]), 
         index=[chr(97+x) for x in (range(n))] + df.index.tolist(),
         columns=[chr(97+x) for x in (range(n))] + df.columns.tolist())
df2


       a    b  jkl  opq  xyz
a    1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
b    0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
abc  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
efg  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
lmn  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Now we can assign the values of `df` to the subset of `df2`

```
df2.ix[n:,n:] = df
df2

       a    b  jkl   opq  xyz
a    1.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.0
b    0.0  1.0  0.0  0.00  0.0
abc  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.00  0.9
efg  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.00  0.3
lmn  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.23  0.0
```

**Timing:** For a `df` of size `(100000,1000)`

```
CPU times: user 6.82 s, sys: 4.52 s, total: 11.3 s
Wall time: 13.1 s
```

---

### Update: Faster

I found a faster version:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100000,1000))
old_cols = df.columns.tolist()
old_index = df.index.tolist()

# Prepend rows: Create n rows and append existing df to this
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(n, df.shape[1])),
             index=[chr(97+x) for x in (range(n))],
             columns=old_cols)
df1 = df1.append(df)

# This was slower
#df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(df1.shape[0],n)),
#             index=df1.index,
#             columns=[chr(97+x) for x in (range(n))])
#df_final = pd.concat([df2,df1], axis=1)

# Create n columns and set to zeros
for i in range(n):
    df1[chr(97+i)] = 0

# Reindex coluns in correct order
df1 = df1[[chr(97+x) for x in (range(n))] + old_cols]

# Assign identity to the top left corner
df1.iloc[:n,:n] = np.identity(n)
```

Timing: For a `df` of size `(100000,1000)`

```
CPU times: user 2.26 s, sys: 1.35 s, total: 3.61 s
Wall time: 3.64 s
```